# SharePoint Web Developer

Tags: books, tutorials

Most of my 8yrs career as a Web designer & Developer, I've designed in Photoshop, hand-coded in HTML and used a PHP-based CMS like Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla. But I've just received a *very* lucrative job offer which requires SharePoint experience.

Since I know absolutely nothing about MS technology (I'm on Mac) or SharePoint, can you please suggest some good beginner article/books that explain SharePoint from a web developer's perspective. I'm an advanced user and a quicker learner so I want to learn SharePoint to not miss this opportunity.

Also, I wonder if its possible to host it locally and learn?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked many times on these StackExchange forums and elsewhere. The results from a Google search for "getting started with sharepoint development" will answer this question very thoroughly.

Here an example: [How can I learn the basics of SharePoint 2013 in a few days?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56596/how-can-i-learn-the-basics-of-sharepoint-2013-in-a-few-days?rq=1)