# Best learning guides for SharePoint beginners

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I am in IT (not a developer) so I won't need to delve as far as work flows as such but I'm starting to get more hands on use of SharePoint 2013 and even the basics I'm resorting to google for.

Is there any SharePoint administration books you would recommend for beginners, I'm tech savvy but no clue about SharePoint.

This may not be the best question for this site, bit like many beginners, we look for answers here so any books/material you'd recommend would come in useful.

Comment: http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some good links.

- [Resources for learning Microsoft Office SharePoint Server](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Resources-for-learning-Microsoft-Office-SharePoint-Server-031D811F-2AE5-45D3-A3D2-BC7A3A9EEDE3)
- Check this for books [Top SharePoint Books](http://sharepoint-community.net/page/top-books)
- Good Resource for learning [How to learn SharePoint and where to get the training](https://www.collaboris.com/how-to-learn-sharepoint-and-where-to-get-the-training/)
- You can go for the [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/), they offer trail.
- another way is check the MSDN Channel 9

Comment: Thanks, these are actually some fairly good materials to go by.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from

[SharePoint 2013 training for developers;](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp123633.aspx)

[SharePoint 2013 development overview.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp123633.aspx)

Also as SharePoint 2013 is very similar to SharePoint 2010 you could periodically stumble into some articles related to SP2010. I could suggest some things to keep in mind about their differences:

InfoPath seems to be deprecated in SP2013. So take a look at ASP.Net forms instead.
New SP2013 Workflow manager doesn't support code workflows, so don't waste your time to understand how Visual Studio (code) WFs work in SP2010 (it is very difficult part of the development which is not actual anymore).
Pay some attention to Client Side Object Model. It is becoming very common (especially in new SP2013 apps) to use it.

For more infor - [How can I learn the basics of SharePoint 2013 in a few days?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56596/how-can-i-learn-the-basics-of-sharepoint-2013-in-a-few-days?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Another good resource is the [SharePoint section of Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/product-training/sharepoint).